# Trying to open pdf in chrome new tab

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am having users save files to the e: drive on my server all that logic works but when I try to allow them to click a url to open and view the pdf or whatever they saved on my server it will not do anything. I want it to open on new window. Here is my code

```
<a href="@Url.Content(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProjectDocLocation"]){{:Project_Code}}{{:Link}}" target="_blank">{{:Link}}</a>

<add key="ProjectDocLocation"
    value="e:\KPOnline.Documents\KPM\ProjectDoc\"
    xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" />
```

Comment: When you click the link, does it at least open the new browser tab?

Comment: no it does not and if I right click and open to a new tab it just gives me about:blank blocked

Comment: Then whatever you're trying to generate for the `href` attribute is probably malformed, and thus not producing proper HTML. Is "ProjectDocLocation" in your config an HTTP URL or a Windows path?

Comment: Never mind, I see you put it right there. Adding a Windows path will not work in modern browsers anymore. If you're going to host in IIS, I suggest creating a [virtual directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/site/application/virtualdirectory) as an alias for the doc share. Then you can create links using a proper `http://` address.

Comment: so when I publish my mvc app it deletes everything and then publishes every folder would I need to create this virtual directory every time? Is there anyways I can create a folder inside my mvc and call it a virtual directory to the file share?

Comment: @Versailles so i was trying to test out the virtual directory locally <application path="/">
                    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="%IIS_SITES_HOME%\WebSite1" />
                  <virtualDirectory path="/Content/KPM/ProjectDoc" physicalPath="C:\KPOnline.Documents\KPM\ProjectDoc\"/>
                </application>  I added this to my IIS express and this is where I have my regular web config saving the documents locally my transforms is in my E drive. but I get page not found when I try out this code. I did a save on the file and the file is in that path

Comment: http://localhost:4399/Content/KPM/ProjectDoc/MGM-BDB-001/sample.pdf  this is my dynamically built url and my physical path would be this  for local testing C:\Temp\KPOnline.Documents\KPM\ProjectDoc\MGM-BDB-001